# Program with particular MS Paint feature?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-editor

I have been looking for an image editing program with a extremely convenient feature from Microsoft Paint. MS Paint allows you to hold the right mouse button while erasing over a region to erase ONLY the selected color and not affect any other color:

[image]

Are there any other programs that have this or a very similar feature? I have been looking into Pinta but have not found this feature yet. The closest thing I have found is the magic wand tool, which doesn't do exactly what I want since it either selects only one region with a particular color or a global feature where selects ALL regions of a particular color in the entire image.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with Gimp, although there are some limitations.
Gimp is available on Ubuntu from the software center.

### Step One: Add Alpha Channel

Once your image is open, right click on the thumbnail of your image inside the *Layers - Brushes* tab/window and select *Add Alpha Channel*.  If this option is greyed out, you can skip this and go the next step.  If you don't have an alpha channel, this will not work.

### Step Two: Select Color to Erase

Use whatever method you prefer to select the color you wish to erase.  It is important that this color be set as the foreground color.

### Step Three: Color Erase Mode

From the *Toolbox - Tool Options* tab/window, select the *Paintbrush* tool.  In the *Tool Options*, set the mode from **Normal** to **Color Erase**.  The paintbrush will now erase the selected foreground color and set it to transparent.

This will work with the Paintbrush, Bucket Fill, Pencil and Airbrush tools.

Comment: My problem lies in the inability to easily select a region of the same color easily. Gimp (and Pinta) can only select ALL regions of a particular color, or a single continuous region, but I do not know how to select several regions close together without selecting every region. (i.e. it is too annoying to manually select several unconnected pixels of the same color) Since this question is more specific to GIMP, I will probably just ask my question on the GIMP forums or resort to getting MS Paint to work with WINE. Thanks!

Comment: Adjusting the "Threshold" slider for the Select by Color or Fuzzy Select tools will help select a smaller or larger area. You can then build on your selection with "add" mode (hold `shift` while selecting).